# jquery: how to store data using jquery function for different drop downs

Tags: jquery

I have a drop down menu and notes that I want to save in memory before sending them to the database. I am using the data function to store the data. But I want it to add a new item each time the dropdown selection is changed

The dropdown and the note are associated so a user will select different drop downs and enter notes. Once they are done, they will save and the data goes into the database. Currently it keeps overwriting the dataobject. How do I prevent that?

my html:

```
<select id="dpselect">
<option value="technical">Technical</option>
<option value="memory">memory link</option>
<option value="version">version</option>
</select>

<textarea id="Note" rows="4" cols="60" maxlength="250">
```

my jquery:

```
var dataObj = {};
//Handle data store when dropdown value is changed
$('#dpselect').change(function() {
    var dpvalue = $('#dpselect').val();
    $(dataObj).data("type", dpvalue);
});

//Handle data store when note value is changed
$('#Note').blur(function() {
    var note = $('#Note').val();
    $(dataObj).data("Note", note);
});
```

Comment: Do you just want one note for each type from the dropdown....or array of notes for each type?

Comment: Hi @charlietfl, i want just one note for each type of dropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it where you use the values of `<select>` as property names for the object and the note text as values for that specific type.

Use the change event of the select to update the textarea so you can also toggle between the different notes.

Something like:

```js
var dataObj = {};
//Handle data store when dropdown value is changed
$('#dpselect').change(function() {
  var type = $(this).val();
  $('#Note').val(dataObj[type] || '')
  console.clear()
  console.log(dataObj)
});

//Handle data store when note value is changed
$('#Note').blur(function() {
  // get current selected type from dropdown
  var type = $('#dpselect').val()
  var note = $('#Note').val();
  // update stored note for that type
  dataObj[type] = note;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dpselect">
  <option value="technical">Technical</option>
  <option value="memory">memory link</option>
  <option value="version">version</option>
</select> 
<br/>
<textarea id="Note" rows="4" cols="60" maxlength="250"></textarea>
```

Comment: Hi @charlietfl, this is exactly what I wanted. Thank you so much. I appreciate it a lot.